# Lining up GameObjects in unity

Tags: unity, c#

I am trying to make a script that lines up a list of GameObjects. Currently, I do this by generating a set of positions and then lerping the objects to them, the code works but does not account for the object's size so if it is large enough clipping will occur. I don't care if the solution is an improvement to the existing code or something entirely new.
This is my current code:

private List GenLinePos(List objs)
{

```
    float curHoldOffset = lineOffset;
    List<Vector3> positions = new List<Vector3>();
    positions.Add(lineAnchor.transform.position);
    int side = 1;
    for(int i = 1; i < objs.Count; i++)
    {
        //set initial position
        Vector3 pos = lineAnchor.transform.position;
        //change position
        pos += (lineAnchor.transform.forward * curHoldOffset) * side;
        side *= -1;
        if(side == 1)
        {
            curHoldOffset += lineOffset;
        }
        positions.Add(pos);
    }
    return positions;
}
```

Note: the line anchor is parented to the main camera which will be moving and rotating

Comment: Have you considered using the objects' `Renderer.bounds` to estimate the spacing needed?

Comment: Yes, but I don't know how to account for the rotation of the objects, I tried rotating them to zero but that crashed unity for some reason.

Comment: The bounds reflect the current worldspace bounding box, accounting for the object's rotation already. What specific problems did you observe when using the bounds as-is without trying to compensate for rotation?

Comment: Sorry, I misspoke. I do not know how to get the specific measurement I need(which axis to use)

Comment: You're positioning objects along `lineAnchor.transform.forward`, so that gives you the axis. In your application, is that typically aligned to a world axis, or diagonal to them?

Comment: Could be either, the line anchor is parented to the camera

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
private List<Vector3> GenLinePos(List<GameObject> objs) {
    float curHoldOffset = lineOffset;
    List<Vector3> positions = new List<Vector3>();
    positions.Add(lineAnchor.transform.position);
    int side = 1;

    for (int i = 1; i < objs.Count; i++) {
        // Set initial position and rotation
        Vector3 pos = lineAnchor.transform.position;
        Quaternion rot = lineAnchor.transform.rotation;

        // Get the object's renderer and transform
        Renderer renderer = objs[i].GetComponent<Renderer>();
        Transform objTransform = objs[i].transform;

        if (renderer != null) {
            // Calculate the additional offset based on object size
            float objectSize = renderer.bounds.size.z;
            curHoldOffset += objectSize;
        }

        // Apply rotation to the position
        pos += rot * (lineAnchor.transform.forward * curHoldOffset) * side;

        // Apply rotation to the object's transform
        objTransform.rotation = rot;

        side *= -1;
        positions.Add(pos);
    }

    return positions;
}
```

Comment: This answer could be improved if you added a brief description of what's happening with this code snippet.

Comment: It seems to send all objects to the same position

Comment: @BluzeOcean CORRECTION: that issue was my fault. However, it does not seem to align them with the lineAnchors transform.forward.
EDIT: the offset is also uneven for some reason.

Comment: @Bluze Ocean after tweaking the object hierarchy the issue with alignment is fixed, the mismatched offset still occurs(sides are not symmetrical) but the code you provided is functional. Thank you.